# Subtotal and Grand Total

Tags: magento-1.7, totals

I working with Quotations in CMS, when I submit Qoute in my mail I have Subtotal and Grand total, the only difference is Grand total get plus with Shipping (Qquoteadv module). If customer has discount both of totals already get minus this discount.

How to make subtotal without discount?

Thanks

Comment: yes very good functionality I developed this functionality couple of days ago so you have to create the module and create some observer for that.

Comment: My memory says, I implemented this too and two weeks later I got angry, because I discovered a configuration setting for this. I can't remember what, but I think there was one.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the extension being responsible for the discount, you can edit its Totals Model... After found the responsible extension look for the totam model, generally the path is like this: Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Totalname.php .

There you will have to edit the collect() method and mabye the fetch() method... The collect is responsible for update the values of the quote, the fetch is responsible to show that labels of discount after subtotal and before grandtotal...

I think in the collect the must have something like:

```
$address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $discount);
```

generally is something like this just change the getGrandTotal to getSubtotal, maybe it works...